# Is there any widget equivalent to UIMenuController in Flutter with which I can customize the actions after the user selects some texts in webview?

Tags: flutter

I use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) to show a webview. Now I want to select some texts in the webview and show a popup action menu(something like the UIMenuController in iOS) to do some custom actions with the texts, such as translate them into another language or mark them to read later, so how can I get the selected texts?

I searched google and flutter github issues with keyword 'flutter webview text select', 'flutter webview text edit', 'flutter webview uimenucontroller' and so on, however I found nothing useful.

The code I am using to show a webview is as as follows:

```
class SessionDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Session session;

  SessionDetailPage({Key key, @required this.session}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SessionDetailState createState() => new _SessionDetailState();
}

class _SessionDetailState extends State<SessionDetailPage> {

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

    Future<bool> _requestPop() {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.session);

      return Future.value(false);
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            widget.session.sessionTitle,
          ),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: widget.session.sessionUrlString,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {

            },
          );
        }),
      ),
      onWillPop: _requestPop,
    );
  }
}
```